# Is it possible to vectorize scipy.optimize.fminbound?

Tags: python, scipy, vectorization, minimization

I have some data points of a trajectory that is parameterized by time, and I want to know the shortest distance of each point to the curve fitted to them. There seem to be several ways to go about this (e.g. [here](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/02/14/Find-the-minimum-distance-from-a-point-to-a-curve/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869154/5472354)), but I chose [`scipy.optimize.fminbound`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fminbound.html?highlight=scipy%20optimize%20fminbound#scipy.optimize.fminbound), as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102112/5472354) (because it seemed to be the slickest way of going about it, and because I actually got it to work):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import fminbound


data = np.array(
    [
        (212.82275865, 1650.40828168, 0., 0),
        (214.22056952, 1649.99898924, 10.38, 0),
        (212.86786868, 1644.25228805, 116.288, 0),
        (212.78680031, 1643.87461108, 122.884, 0),
        (212.57489485, 1642.01124032, 156.313, 0),
        (212.53483954, 1641.61858242, 162.618, 0),
        (212.43922274, 1639.58782771, 196.314, 0),
        (212.53726315, 1639.13842423, 202.619, 0),
        (212.2888428, 1637.24641296, 236.306, 0),
        (212.2722447, 1636.92307229, 242.606, 0),
        (212.15559302, 1635.0529813, 276.309, 0),
        (212.17535631, 1634.60618711, 282.651, 0),
        (212.02545613, 1632.72139574, 316.335, 0),
        (211.99988779, 1632.32053329, 322.634, 0),
        (211.33419846, 1631.07592039, 356.334, 0),
        (211.58972239, 1630.21971902, 362.633, 0),
        (211.70332122, 1628.2088542, 396.316, 0),
        (211.74610735, 1627.67591368, 402.617, 0),
        (211.88819518, 1625.67310022, 436.367, 0),
        (211.90709414, 1625.39410321, 442.673, 0),
        (212.00090348, 1623.42655008, 476.332, 0),
        (211.9249017, 1622.94540583, 482.63, 0),
        (212.34321938, 1616.32949197, 597.329, 0),
        (213.09638942, 1615.2869643, 610.4, 0),
        (219.41313491, 1580.22234313, 1197.332, 0),
        (220.38660128, 1579.20043302, 1210.37, 0),
        (236.35472669, 1542.30863041, 1798.267, 0),
        (237.41755384, 1541.41679119, 1810.383, 0),
        (264.08373622, 1502.66620597, 2398.244, 0),
        (265.65655239, 1501.64308908, 2410.443, 0),
        (304.66999824, 1460.94068336, 2997.263, 0),
        (306.22550945, 1459.75817211, 3010.38, 0),
        (358.88879764, 1416.472238, 3598.213, 0),
        (361.14046402, 1415.40942931, 3610.525, 0),
        (429.96379858, 1369.7972467, 4198.282, 0),
        (432.06565776, 1368.22265539, 4210.505, 0),
        (519.30493383, 1319.01141844, 4798.277, 0),
        (522.12134083, 1317.68234967, 4810.4, 0),
        (630.00294242, 1265.05368942, 5398.236, 0),
        (633.67624272, 1263.63633508, 5410.431, 0),
        (766.29767476, 1206.91262814, 5997.266, 0),
        (770.78300649, 1205.48393374, 6010.489, 0),
        (932.92308019, 1145.87780431, 6598.279, 0),
        (937.54373403, 1141.55438694, 6609.525, 0),
    ], dtype=[
        ('x', 'f8'), ('y', 'f8'), ('t', 'f8'), ('dmin', 'f8'),
    ]
)

# fyi my data comes as a structured array; unfortunately, simply passing
# data[['x', 'y']] to np.polyfit does not work. using
# pd.DataFrame(data[['x', y']]).values seems to be the easiest solution:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/26175750/5472354
coeffs = np.polyfit(
    data['t'], pd.DataFrame(data[['x', 'y']]).values, 3
)


def curve(t):
    # this can probably also be done in one statement, but I don't know how
    x = np.polyval(coeffs[:, 0], t)
    y = np.polyval(coeffs[:, 1], t)

    return x, y


def f(t, p):
    x, y = curve(t)
    return np.hypot(x - p['x'], y - p['y'])


# instead of this:
for point in data:
    tmin = fminbound(f, -50, 6659.525, args=(point, ))
    point['dmin'] = f(tmin, point)


# do something like this:
# tmin = fminbound(f, -50, 6659.525, args=(data, ))
# data['dmin'] = f(tmin, data)
```

But as you can see, I use a `for`-loop to calculate the shortest distances for each data point, which slows down my program significantly, as this is performed several thousand times. Thus I would like to vectorize the operation / improve the performance, but haven't found a way. There are related posts to this (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59371930/5472354) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10828477/5472354)), but I don't know how the suggested solutions apply in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to vectorize `fminbound` since it expects a **scalar function of one variable**. However, you can still vectorize the loop by reformulating the underlying mathematical optimization problem:

The `N` scalar optimization problems

```
min f_1(t) s.t. t_l <= t <= t_u
min f_2(t) s.t. t_l <= t <= t_u
.
.
.
min f_N(t) s.t. t_l <= t <= t_u
```

for scalar functions `f_i` are equivalent to one optimization problem
in `N` variables:

```
min f_1(t_1)**2 + ... + f_N(t_N)**2  s.t. t_l <= t_i <= t_u for all i = 1, .., N
```

which can be solved by means of [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize). Depending on your whole algorithm, you could use this approach to further eliminate more loops, i.e. you only solve one large-scale optimization problem instead of multiple thousands of scalar optimization problems.

After cleaning up your code, this can be done as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

data = np.array([
    (212.82275865, 1650.40828168, 0., 0),
    (214.22056952, 1649.99898924, 10.38, 0),
    (212.86786868, 1644.25228805, 116.288, 0),
    (212.78680031, 1643.87461108, 122.884, 0),
    (212.57489485, 1642.01124032, 156.313, 0),
    (212.53483954, 1641.61858242, 162.618, 0),
    (212.43922274, 1639.58782771, 196.314, 0),
    (212.53726315, 1639.13842423, 202.619, 0),
    (212.2888428, 1637.24641296, 236.306, 0),
    (212.2722447, 1636.92307229, 242.606, 0),
    (212.15559302, 1635.0529813, 276.309, 0),
    (212.17535631, 1634.60618711, 282.651, 0),
    (212.02545613, 1632.72139574, 316.335, 0),
    (211.99988779, 1632.32053329, 322.634, 0),
    (211.33419846, 1631.07592039, 356.334, 0),
    (211.58972239, 1630.21971902, 362.633, 0),
    (211.70332122, 1628.2088542, 396.316, 0),
    (211.74610735, 1627.67591368, 402.617, 0),
    (211.88819518, 1625.67310022, 436.367, 0),
    (211.90709414, 1625.39410321, 442.673, 0),
    (212.00090348, 1623.42655008, 476.332, 0),
    (211.9249017, 1622.94540583, 482.63, 0),
    (212.34321938, 1616.32949197, 597.329, 0),
    (213.09638942, 1615.2869643, 610.4, 0),
    (219.41313491, 1580.22234313, 1197.332, 0),
    (220.38660128, 1579.20043302, 1210.37, 0),
    (236.35472669, 1542.30863041, 1798.267, 0),
    (237.41755384, 1541.41679119, 1810.383, 0),
    (264.08373622, 1502.66620597, 2398.244, 0),
    (265.65655239, 1501.64308908, 2410.443, 0),
    (304.66999824, 1460.94068336, 2997.263, 0),
    (306.22550945, 1459.75817211, 3010.38, 0),
    (358.88879764, 1416.472238, 3598.213, 0),
    (361.14046402, 1415.40942931, 3610.525, 0),
    (429.96379858, 1369.7972467, 4198.282, 0),
    (432.06565776, 1368.22265539, 4210.505, 0),
    (519.30493383, 1319.01141844, 4798.277, 0),
    (522.12134083, 1317.68234967, 4810.4, 0),
    (630.00294242, 1265.05368942, 5398.236, 0),
    (633.67624272, 1263.63633508, 5410.431, 0),
    (766.29767476, 1206.91262814, 5997.266, 0),
    (770.78300649, 1205.48393374, 6010.489, 0),
    (932.92308019, 1145.87780431, 6598.279, 0),
    (937.54373403, 1141.55438694, 6609.525, 0)])

# the coefficients
coeffs = np.polyfit(data[:, 2], data[:, 0:2], 3)

# the points
points = data[:, :2]

# vectorized version of your objective function
# i.e. evaluates f_1, ..., f_N
def f(t, points):
    poly_x = np.polyval(coeffs[:, 0], t)
    poly_y = np.polyval(coeffs[:, 1], t)
    return np.hypot(poly_x - points[:, 0], poly_y - points[:, 1])

# the scalar objective function we want to minimize
def obj_vec(t, points):
    vals = f(t, points)
    return np.sum(vals**2)

# variable bounds
bnds = [(-50, 6659.525)]*len(points)

# solve the optimization problem
res = minimize(lambda t: obj_vec(t, points), x0=np.zeros(len(points)), bounds=bnds)
dmins = f(res.x, points)
```

In order to further accelerate the optimization, it's highly recommended to pass the exact gradient of the objective function to `minimize`. Currently, the gradient is approximated by finite differences, which is quite slow:

```py
In [7]: %timeit res = minimize(lambda t: obj_vec(t, points), x0=np.zeros(len(points)), bounds=bnds)
91.5 ms ± 868 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

<s>Since the gradient can easily be computed by the chain rule, I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader :).</s> By the chain rule, the gradient reads as

```py
def grad(t, points):
    poly_x = np.polyval(coeffs[:, 0], t)
    poly_y = np.polyval(coeffs[:, 1], t)
    poly_x_deriv = np.polyval(np.polyder(coeffs[:, 0], m=1), t)
    poly_y_deriv = np.polyval(np.polyder(coeffs[:, 1], m=1), t)
    return 2*poly_x_deriv*(poly_x - points[:, 0]) + 2*(poly_y_deriv)*(poly_y - points[:, 1])
```

and passing it to `minimize` significantly reduces the runtime:

```py
In [9]: %timeit res = minimize(lambda t: obj_vec(t, points), jac=lambda t: grad(t, points), x0=np.zeros(len(points)),
     ...: bounds=bnds)
6.13 ms ± 63.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Finally, setting another starting point might also lead to fewer iterations, as you already noted in the comments.

Comment: Reformulating the mathematical problem is a great idea. I would have never thought of that. Thanks! Just one question: Why do you choose zeroes as the initial guesses? I think sticking with the times that are closer to the actual solution (i.e. the times in the dataset) is probably faster, no?

Comment: Ok, I just did a basic speed test for 100 runs, and it seems like using the times from the dataset as the initial guess makes the operation faster (~6s vs. ~9s), however, the original for loop approach is even faster still (~3s). I don't really understand why though. I was pretty certain that vectorization would significantly improve the runtime.

Comment: @mapf The reason is simple: The gradient is calculated by finite differences, so **each** evaluation of the gradient leads to **many** evaluations of the objective function. That's why it's worth providing the exact gradient, as noted at the end of my answer. Feel free to do another speed test with the exact gradient as shown in the edited answer. And yes, using a better initial point can also lead to fewer iterations.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the extra effort. Much appreciated.

Comment: I just ran my own quick speed test and can confirm that using the gradient is by far the fastest method (the better initial guesses speeds up the process by an additional ~35%).