# Scipy minimize with pandas dataframe with group by

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a data frame (a sample df below) and trying to minimize cost function on that.

```
GrpId = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
col1 = [69.1,70.5,71.4,72.8,73.2,74.2,208.0,209.2,210.2,211.0,211.2,211.7,212.5]
col2 = [2,3.1,1.1,2.1,6.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,3.1,2.9,5.0,6.1,3.2]
d = {'GrpId':GrpId,'col1':col1,'col2':col2}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Below are minimize and cost function.

```
col1_const=[0,0,0,0,60.0,0,0,0]
col2_const=[0,0,0,0,0,100.0,0,0]

def main(type1,type2,type3,df):
    vall0=[type1,type2,type3]
    res=minimize(cost_fun, vall0, args=(df), method = 'SLSQP', tol=0.01)

    [type1,type2,type3]=res.x

    return type1,type2,type3

def cost_fun(v, df):

    df['col1_res'][i] = np.where((df['col1'][i]!=np.nan), ((1/0.095)*(np.sqrt(df['col1'][i])-np.sqrt(col1_const[4]*(0.1*v[1]+v[2])**2)))**2 ,0)
    df['col2_res'][i] = np.where((df['col2'][i]!=np.nan), ((1/0.12)*(np.sqrt(df['col2'][i])-np.sqrt(col2_const[5]*(0.1*v[0]+v[2])**2)))**2 ,0)   
    
    res=0.5*np.sqrt(df['col1_res'][i]+df['col2_res'][i])

    return res
```

Then I'm iterating this function in loop as below, which is working but takes lot of time and memory,

```
df1['type1']=np.nan
df1['type2']=np.nan
df1['type3']=np.nan
df1['col3']=np.nan
df1['col1_res']=np.nan
df1['col2_res']=np.nan

for i in range(len(df1.GrpId)):
    if i==0:
        df1['type1'][i], df1['type2'][i], df1['type3'][i]= main(0.125, 0.125, 0.125,df1)
    else:
        df1['type1'][i], df1['type2'][i], df1['type3'][i]= main(df1['type1'][i-1], df1['type2'][i-1], df1['type3'][i-1],df1)
    df1['col3'][i]=df1['type1'][i]+df1['type2'][i]
```

Please note that I have bigger dataframe with more rows and columns, for this questions I just created a sample code/case.

My questions are,

1. How can I do the same without iteration
2. `col1_const[4]`  value will change as per the group (group by GrpId) - I have another function to calculate col1_const[4] values per group. How can I pass this value to cost_fun in that case by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think it's necessary to check for `!= np.nan` inside the objective function. Instead, you could clean up your dataframe and replace all `np.nan` with zero. The objective function is called several times during the optimization routine, so it should be written as efficient and fast as possible. Consequently, we remove the call of `np.where`. Note also that relying on the fact that the index variable `i`  is known at the outer scope is bad practice and makes the code hard to read. I'd recommend something like this:

```py
col1 = df1.col1.values[df1.col1.values != np.nan]
col2 = df1.col2.values[df1.col2.values != np.nan]
col1_const = np.array([0,0,0,0,60.0,0,0,0])
col2_const = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,100.0,0,0])

def cost_fun1(v, *args):
    i, col1, col2, col1_const, col2_const = args
    col1_res = ((1/0.095)*(np.sqrt(col1[i]) - np.sqrt(col1_const[4]*(0.1*v[1]+v[2])**2)))**2
    col2_res = ((1/0.12)*(np.sqrt(col2[i]) - np.sqrt(col2_const[5]*(0.1*v[0]+v[2])**2)))**2
    return 0.5*np.sqrt(col1_res + col2_res)
```

Next, and more importantly, you are solving multiple optimization problems instead of solving one large-scale optimization problem. Mathematically, because your objective function is guaranteed to be positive, you can reformulate your problem in the same vein to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786214/is-it-possible-to-vectorize-scipy-optimize-fminbound/69787093#69787093). Then, `cost_fun2` basically returns the sum of all `cost_fun1` for all indices i. Using a bit of reshaping magic, the function nearly looks the same:

```
def cost_fun2(vv, *args):
    col1, col2, col1_const, col2_const = args
    v = vv.reshape(3, col1.size)
    col1_res = ((1/0.095)*(np.sqrt(col1) - np.sqrt(col1_const[4]*(0.1*v[1]+v[2])**2)))**2
    col2_res = ((1/0.12)*(np.sqrt(col2) - np.sqrt(col2_const[5]*(0.1*v[0]+v[2])**2)))**2
    return np.sum(0.5*np.sqrt(col1_res + col2_res))
```

Then, we simply solve the problem and write the solution values into the dataframe afterwards:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# initial guess
x0 = np.ones(3*col1.size)

# solve the problem
res = minimize(lambda vv: cost_fun2(vv, col1, col2, col1_const, col2_const), x0=x0, method="trust-constr")

# write to dataframe
type1_vals, type2_vals, type3_vals = np.split(res.x, 3)
df1['type1'] = type1_vals
df1['type2'] = type2_vals
df1['type3'] = type3_vals
```

If you need `col1_res` and `col2_res` in the dataframe, it's straighforward to modify the objective function accordingly.

Last but not least, depending on the size of your dataframe, it's highly recommended to pass the exact objective gradient to `scipy.optimize.minimize` in order to obtain a good convergence performance. At the moment, the gradient is approximated by finite differences which is quite slow and prone to rounding errors.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this however I'm getting `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (13,)` at `v = np.reshape(3, col1.size)`. Also, I want to start the initial value `x0= [0.125, 0.125, 0.125]`, but I'm getting error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: There was a tiny typo. Feel free to try it again. You can easily set the initial guess to `x0 = 0.125*np.ones(3*col1.size)` before calling minimize. However, note that you **can't** use the solution of the previous problem as an initial guess for the next subproblem in a vectorized formulation.

Comment: one last question please, I want to add bounds as well. `bnds=((0,0.99999), (0,0.99999), (0,0.2))` and I tried `res = minimize(lambda vv: cost_fun2(vv, col1, col2, col1_const, col2_const), x0=x0, method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bnds, tol=0.01)` . This gave me `IndexError: SLSQP Error: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0`. How can I reshape it

Comment: You have `3*col1.size` variables, so your `bnds` has to contain `3*col1.size` bounds, not 3.